# AppVeyor build failed npm ERR! EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, appveyor

My appveyor build is failing due to below issue, I am not sure why this is happening. build is failing after npm install

npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL type "npm:": npm:string-width@^4.2.0

I tried to change the npm version but it didn't go well.